# How can I remove more libs to reduce loading at startup?

Tags: init-file, start-up, load, site-lisp

When I view the number of commands or functions through `M-x` I notice so many that I never use.  However I also didn't load them explicitly in my `init.el` either.  I do use `use-package` and have attempted to keep my dotfiles small and light, but it occurred to me that I might have some defaults going on in my build of Emacs that includes a number of 'site' libs.  I'm not sure if there might be a recommended minimum, or how to removed these unnecessary libs from startup.  How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to find out whether it is you or `site-lisp.el` that is doing this, start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file), and see if you see the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to remove anything. Emacs has a system called Autoloading that has a list of functions and what file they are defined in, and only loads the file when the function is called. This means that most of the functions you see in that list are things that are not yet fully loaded. They will only be fully loaded the first time you use them.